# Compile Error: 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer. Working with structs

Tags: c++, function, pointers, vector, struct

My programming assignment wants me define a structure Student with a name vector, and a structure Course with a name and a vector  that contains enrolled students and the following functions:

```
void print_student(Student* s)
void print_course(Course* c)
void enroll(Student* s, Course* c)
//enrolls given student in the given course and updates both vectors
```

I tried adding ampersands within the enroll function parameters to fix it, but it didn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Student 
{
    string Name ;
    vector < Course* > Courses;
};

struct Course 
{
    string Name ;
    vector < Student* > Students;
};

void print_Student(Student* s)
{
    cout << s->Name << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < s->Courses.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << s->Courses[i] << endl;
    }
};

void print_course(Course* c)
{
    cout << c->Name << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < c->Students.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << c->Students[i] << endl;
    }
};

void enroll(Student* &s, Course* &c)
{
    cout << "Enrolled " << s << "in " << c << endl;
    s->Courses.push_back( c ); 
    c->Students.push_back( s);
}


int main()
{
    Student* Bob;
    Course* ComputerScience;

    Bob->Name = "Bob";

    ComputerScience->Name = "Computer Science";

    enroll( Bob , ComputerScience);

    system("Pause");
}
```

I expected the code to enroll the student Bob to the Computer Science course so I can later define more students and print them.

The code seems good but,when running the compiler gives me the following errors:

```
source.cpp(10): error C2065: 'Course': undeclared identifier
source.cpp(10): error C2059: syntax error: '>'
source.cpp(10): error C2976: 'std::vector': too few template arguments
source.cpp(41): error C2663: 'std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc>::push_back': 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer
```

I'm confused on what's going on, and how could I fix it?

Comment: First, before `cout << c->Name << endl;` you should check that `c` is not `null`.

Comment: Second, `Student* Bob` and then `Bob->Name = "Bob";` will most likely crash. `Bob` is not initialized (or initialized with garbage). You should do `Student* Bob= new Studend;` and at the end of the program `delete Bob;`, use a `unique_ptr` or do `Student Bob;`, then `Bob.Name= "Bob";` and finally call `enroll(&Bob, &ComputerScience);` (same aplies to ComputerScience).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you compile the code, the compiler begins compiling struct Student before compiling struct Course. Hence at the time of compiling Student, the compiler doesn't know what Course is. Therefore the error, undeclared identifier. To fix it, forward declare struct Course like this:

```
struct Course;
struct Student 
 {
   string Name ;
   vector < Course* > Courses;
 };


struct Course 
 {
   string Name ;
   vector < Student* > Students;
 };
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem, but now another error. Im confused as there both initialized?
 error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'Bob' used
 error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'ComputerScience'

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your code. I suggest you to learn about pointers, dynamic memory allocation and operator overloading before writing this program. The compiler error is pretty straight forward. You have declared pointers Student* and Course* but did not allocate any memory address for them. Also, in your enroll function, you are trying to cout an entire struct. How is cout supposed to know your struct structure to be able to output its values? You can output entire struct with a cout once you have learnt about operator overloading. Until then just cout specific structs variables.

Comment: For now you can either switch to objects or use the **new** keyword to dynamically allocate memory for your struct pointers. You will also have to **delete** this memory when you are done. `Student *Bob = new Student` and then later `delete Bob`. Same for Course* ComputerScience.